# How to find length of first row in list?

Tags: c#, generics

```
List<object> list = Infoware.StudentModules.ToList<object>();
```

Here I will get nth rows with n elements in each row? Now I need to find
no of elements in first row.

Comment: The first element in a list you can get by using `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()` or `ElementAt()`

Comment: What is `StudentModules` and what does it store? Why do you use `òbject` instead of the real type?

Comment: To use First() FirstOrDefault() or ElementAt() you need to import System.Linq

Comment: Here StudentModules is a table in my entity framework since crystalReport.SetDataSource() Method need a Datatable I am converting List of type StudentModules to Datatable

Answer (score 0):

You Can use 
`list.First()` or `list.FirstOrDefault()`  for getting For Get First Row 
and also use **`list.ElementAt()`** method for find particular row
Or Also use **List[0].**

Comment: `InfowareEntities Infoware = new InfowareEntities();           ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument(); crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/" + Report)); crystalReport.SetDataSource(Infoware.StudentModules.ToList()); `   **Here StudentModules is a table in my entity framework since crystalReport.SetDataSource() Method need a Datatable I am converting List of type StudentModules to Datatable**

Comment: Pls Explain in brief What you cant @TaqiGates

Comment: I Need to create datatable with columns as the max no of Elements in the collections and rows as the List Count.

Comment: Lets say This is my list  {0,1,2,8 }                                                                                                     {4,5,8,9  }                                                                                                                Here their are two rows I can get the rowcount by list.count but I need to get the count of elements in first row which is 4. How can i get that